# Installing dependencies from a gemspec file

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I wish to work on an existing gem, which I've checked out from a git repository.  I'm using a clean Ruby installation.  To start, I would like to install the dependencies specified in the gemspec file so that I can build and test the gem.  I'm not using bundler for this.

Currently, I manually install the gems by reading the gemspec and invoking 'gem'.  What I'd like to do is something like:

```
git clone my_gem
cd my_gem
gem magically-install-dependencies my_gem.gemspec
```

and have all of the runtime and development dependencies installed as they would be if I'd installed this from a .gem file.  Is there a way to do this?

I've searched the `gem` documentation and there doesn't seem to be anything that works on gemfiles other than `build`.

Comment: Why don‘t you want to use bundler?

Comment: Mostly because I want to keep dependencies as simple as possible. Bundler is yet another set of complexities I wish to avoid.

Comment: The RubyGems API has a way to read and analyze gemspec files. In its simplest form you could just extract the gems and their version requirements using the API. But remember that from a complex set of version requirements, it might not be a straightforward process to find a set of mutually matching gem versions. The brute force approach is to just install the minimum required versions of all gems in the gemspec file, but I am not 100% sure if this guarantees success in all cases. That is why we have Bundler. It might work in 99% of cases though. No clue on the stats.

Comment: In any case this approach requires that you write a small tool that does the gemspec extraction. You could include this piece of code in the repository, for example.